# Apache 2.4 stopped logging

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, log-files

I have a VirtualHost being served on an Apache 2.4 box and recently noticed that neither the Error nor Access logs are being written to. I can't recall making any changes to the files that would have caused this.

The VirtualHost file is as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName server.domain.com
  ServerAlias server.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /web/app/public_html
  ErrorLog /var/www/app/error_log
  CustomLog /var/www/app/access_log combined

<Directory "/web/app/public_html">
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have almost this exact code running on a dev box with no issues so I am not sure why the logs are failing to write.

I've ensured the permissions are correct on the files, tried disabling SELinux for testing and re-creating the log files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT : Output of ls -la /var/www/app

```
[user@server]# ls -la /var/www/app/
total 5588
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root     root         4096 May 23 11:57 .
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root     root         4096 Apr 12 17:04 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 http     http       0 May 23 11:25 access_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root     root      5673320 Feb 24 09:35 access_log.bak
-rw-r--r--. 1 http     http   24643 Feb 24 08:06 error_log
```

EDIT 2 : It seems as though the log files have reverted back to the the default paths and are being stored in the following locations.

```
/var/log/httpd/access_log
/var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log
/var/log/httpd/error_log
/var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log
```

It looks as though the logging in my virtual host config file is being ignored all together. Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Please share output of `ls -la /var/www/app/`.

Comment: @AlexanderT edited question with requested output

Comment: move existing access and error logs out of the way and try restarting Apache

Comment: @Safado No love I'm afraid.

Comment: check httpd.conf for LogLevel **warn** change to LogLevel **info**, for more details check [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel), dont forget to reload apache, *service httpd reload* you can also check if you have any syntax/typo errors before reload using *httpd -t*

Comment: Some things to check for EDIT 2: for the virt host file to be loaded (sounds like it's ignored), make sure: (1) the virt host filename ends in *.conf, (2) is located in 'sites-enabled' or 'conf-enabled' dirs, (3) verify the 'IncludeOptional' commands in the main apache2.conf file that load these dirs aren't commented out, (4) check perms on the virt host file and directory are open for reading to the apache user, (5) after restart of apache, check error_log for syntax errors/file permission errors.